# React add property to immutable object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I'm trying to add a new property to objects within an array. My idea was to do something like this:

```
class Foo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = this.getInitialState();
        console.log(this.state); //Property "label" is missing in "members" array
    }

    /**
     * Get initial state
     * @returns {{title, description}}
     */
    getInitialState = () => {
        let members = this.props.members.slice();
        members.map((member) => {
            return {
                ...member,
                label: (member.firstName + " " + member.lastName)
            }
        });
        console.log(members); //"label" is not a property of objects

        return {title: "", description: "", responsible: [], typeOf: null, 
                members: members};
    };

    render () {
         return (<div/>)
    }
}
```

I want `members` to stay/remain immutable, yet adding another property to every object within this array. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not storing returned value of map to members variable

```
getInitialState = () => {
        let members = this.props.members.map((member) => {
            return {
                ...member,
                label: (member.firstName + " " + member.lastName)
            }
        });
        console.log(members); //"label" is not a property of objects

        return {title: "", description: "", responsible: [], typeOf: null, 
                members: members};
    };
```

Comment: I will ;) Have to wait for 5 min

Comment: @Nocebo added an edit to the answer to show that since `Array#map` already returns a new array, you don't have to use `this.props.members.slice()`.

Comment: you create a new object instead of the original. you might loose closures and other binding to the original object.

Answer (score 1):

The array prototype [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does not mutate the original array, but returns a new array.